# Use MikroORM migrations with NestJs

Tags: nestjs, mikro-orm

I'm running into problem using command `mikro-orm migration:create`. Console shows me `Error: MikroORM config file not found in ['./dist/mikro-orm.config.js', './mikro-orm.config.js']`. My app.module looks like this:

```
  @Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MikroOrmCoreModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        entitiesTs: [`./shared/db/entities`],
        entities: [`./dist/shared/db/entities`],
        user: configService.get<string>('DB_NAME'),
        password: configService.get<string>('DB_PASSWORD'),
        dbName: configService.get<string>('DB_NAME'),
        port: configService.get<number>('DB_PORT'),
        type: 'postgresql',
        migrations: {
          tableName: 'migrations',
          path: `./dist/shared/db/migrations`,
          pathTs: `./shared/db/entities`,
          glob: '!(*.d).{js,ts}',
          transactional: true,
          allOrNothing: true,
          emit: 'ts',
        },
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Aslo I've tried to create `mikro-orm.config` file with same setup, but then console shows me something like `Error: No entities discovered`. I've tried different ways of define paths in all related fields (entitiesTs, entities, path, pathTs) such as using `*`/`__dirname`/`process.pwd()` in path, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the configuration only in the `mikro-orm.config.ts` file, configure the ORM to find it as described in [docs](https://mikro-orm.io/docs/installation#setting-up-the-commandline-tool) (namely the `configPaths` and `useTsNode` in your package.json), then you can use this config in your app.module.ts, just import it and spread to the place where you have the options now. Then you can use the `npx mikro-orm debug` command to check how the paths look for the ORM.

```
import config from './mikro-orm.config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true }),
    MikroOrmCoreModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        ...config,
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This way you get a single source of truth for both the CLI and your app, so you can use the CLI to debug the config easily.